# Code that counts cell with green background value = 0 while in sub Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone teach me how to write code that counts cell with green background and has a value of 0 while in sub `Worksheet_Change`?

Here's my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim total As Integer
lastRow = 5

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Range("B6:B6").Value = 0 + Val(Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 And Cells(i, 2).Value < 1)
Next
Range("B6").Value = total
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub FormattingCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, total As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet  '<< always use an explicit worksheet 
    lastRow = 5

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        With ws.Cells(i, 2)
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = 4 and .Value = 0 Then
                total = total +1
            End If
        End With
    Next
    ws.Range("B6").Value = total

End Sub
```