# Adding value of range("B6") everytime it counts from Range("B1 : B5") cell that has Green Background and value = 0

Tags: excel, vba

I want code that adds a value of range("B6") every time it counts from Range("B1 : B5")  cell that has Green Background and value = 0 while in a `worksheet_Change` event.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastRow = 5
For i = 2 To lastRow
With ws.Cells(i, 2)
If .Interior.ColorIndex = 4 And .Value = 0 Then
MsgBox "Test" ' <----- supposedly range("B6").value .add
End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This would go from 2-5 instead of `B1:B5`. Also, where do you want to `Add` the value of `Range("B6")` exactly? Inside the green cells where current value is 0? Would `.Value = ws.Cells(6,2).Value` inside your `IF` be what you are after?

Comment: @JvdV no bro i want to add the numbers of  cell from b1:b5 that contains green background and value = 0 to range(B6)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You want to add values of zero to the value in B6? So you add nothing? Or do you simply want to `.Count` the cells that are green and hold 0? If the latter, then why would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60201820/9758194) not work?

Comment: Would `ws.Cells(6,2).Value = ws.Cells(6,2).Value + 1` be what you are after then?

Comment: @JvdV i just only want to count the cell that has green background and value = 0 example: only B1 and B3 has green background and value = 0 then range("B6") value = 2 dont count the B2,B4,and B5

Comment: Are cells of that range conditional formatted, or not?

Comment: @FaneDuru nope bro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code that counts cell with green background value = 0 while in sub Worksheet\_Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60201741/code-that-counts-cell-with-green-background-value-0-while-in-sub-worksheet-cha)

Comment: You simple replace `"B1:B"` with `"C1:C"` and use in iteration `ws.Cells(i, 3)` instead of `ws.Cells(i, 2)`. The third column instead of the second...

Comment: @FaneDuru i mean in both B & C column bro

Comment: OK. Not so complicated, but a little more complicated. I will adapt the code from my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this code:

It works only for cell changed in the range `"B1:B" & lastRow`. Would you like to work for any cell changed in all the sheet? I think, it could be annoying...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, iCount As Long, iCountC As Long
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = 5
 Set rng = ws.Range("B1:C" & lastRow)
  If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        With ws.Cells(i, 2)
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = 4 And .Value = 0 Then
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
            If .Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 And _
                            .Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Then
                iCountC = iCountC + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next
    ws.Range("B" & lastRow + 1).Value = iCount
    ws.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Value = iCountC
  End If
End Sub
```

It returns the number of green cells, immediately after the `lastRow`. So, if you modify this number (from 5 to 15), it will return in "B16"...

For your second request I used `.Offset(0, 1)` which means the neighbor cell to the right...

Comment: @Hotdog:I explained you (answering your first question on the issue) how to change the code. If you like me to make the change, it will not be a problem, but you will better memorized (and learn) simple things you understand and do by yourself, I think...

Comment: last question Bro im newbie in VBA

Comment: they're seperate bro the count of C will go to range C6

Comment: Did you un-tick the check box from the left side of the code, making it the answer? Or , did you delete your comment thanking for the provided solution?

Comment: But you did not say that! You just said `i mean in both B & C column bro`... OK. I will adapt it again for this last understanding...

Comment: sorry bro just a little bit patience

Comment: No any problem! I just did not understood that from the way you said...

Comment: I told you. No problem from my side. I am also not a native English speaker and maybe both of us language abilities "helped" a little... :)

Comment: i need Help bro i have a merge cell which my counter counts *2 :(